# Scrivener challenge with page numbers

Tags: scrivener

I am having a challenge with getting page numbering to work in Scrivener (Windows).  I have set Page Header/Footer checked for "Not on page 1", unchecked on "Count page 1". Here is my problem.

I have each chapter (fiction novel) in a separate folder. I want Scrivener to automatically paginate at the bottom.  The field by Footer keeps defaulting to "Enter  for page number". I tried but that seems to necessitate MANUALLY entering that on each page! I put it at the end of the chapter, hoping foolishly that it would auto paginate. It gave the correct page number, but only inserted it on the last page.

Not sure what I'm missing.... Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: The Scrivener tag says - "Use this tag if you have questions about the use of this software.". I think this is a perfectly viable question under this tag. It is possible that the tag should be changed or removed, and I don't know policy here, but this seems to be on topic for the tag

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How do I number chapter pages in scrivener?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/28822/34330)